# Can SPMT Tool do - SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, migration, content-migration, sharepointmigrationtool

Can the SPMT Tool migrate content/Files from SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online?

If not are there any other alternatives  without using a third-party tools?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Can the SharePoint Migration tool (SPMT) migrate content from one SharePoint tenant to another SharePoint tenant?
>
> **Answer**: **No**. SPMT can migrate content from SharePoint on-premises Server, but not from another SharePoint Online tenant. However, a cross-tenant migration solution for SharePoint and OneDrive is available. Learn more at [Cross-tenant OneDrive migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/enterprise/cross-tenant-onedrive-migration?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).

**Source**: [Frequently asked questions: SharePoint Migration tool (SPMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepointmigration/spmt-faqs?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)